# How to fetch complete customer data in magento with address and whole data related to entity_id

Tags: magento-1.8, mysql, query

I need to fetch whole customer data from mysql by query.
I need to get data by entity_id.
I used query

```
SELECT `e`.* FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1');
```

but this is not giving me whole data of customer with his related attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why you need it my query but here is what you can do.
Activate the sql query log.
Edit `/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and set the values for `$_debug` and `$_logAllQueries` to `true`. then create a custom script that just calls

```
$customerId = 1;
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
exit;
```

Then you should see in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` the queries that are executed.
You will see some 'noise' queries but the last ones should be what you need.
Here is what I got:
The first query retrieves the attributes, the second one the data:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`attribute_id`, `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.`is_visible`, `additional_table`.`input_filter`, `additional_table`.`multiline_count`, `additional_table`.`validate_rules`, `additional_table`.`is_system`, `additional_table`.`sort_order`, `additional_table`.`data_model`, `scope_table`.`website_id` AS `scope_website_id`, `scope_table`.`is_visible` AS `scope_is_visible`, `scope_table`.`is_required` AS `scope_is_required`, `scope_table`.`default_value` AS `scope_default_value`, `scope_table`.`multiline_count` AS `scope_multiline_count` FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
 INNER JOIN `customer_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id
 LEFT JOIN `customer_eav_attribute_website` AS `scope_table` ON scope_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND scope_table.website_id = :scope_website_id WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = :mt_entity_type_id)
BIND: array (
  ':mt_entity_type_id' => 1,
  ':scope_website_id' => 1,
)
```

If you remove the bindings you end up with this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.`attribute_id`, `main_table`.`entity_type_id`, `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`, `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`, `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`, `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`, `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`, `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`, `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`, `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.`is_visible`, `additional_table`.`input_filter`, `additional_table`.`multiline_count`, `additional_table`.`validate_rules`, `additional_table`.`is_system`, `additional_table`.`sort_order`, `additional_table`.`data_model`, `scope_table`.`website_id` AS `scope_website_id`, `scope_table`.`is_visible` AS `scope_is_visible`, `scope_table`.`is_required` AS `scope_is_required`, `scope_table`.`default_value` AS `scope_default_value`, `scope_table`.`multiline_count` AS `scope_multiline_count` FROM `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
     INNER JOIN `customer_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id
     LEFT JOIN `customer_eav_attribute_website` AS `scope_table` ON scope_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND scope_table.website_id = 1 WHERE (main_table.entity_type_id = 1);
```

and the query to retrieve all data:

```
SELECT `customer_entity_varchar`.* FROM `customer_entity_varchar` WHERE (entity_id ='1') 
    UNION ALL SELECT `customer_entity_int`.* FROM `customer_entity_int` WHERE (entity_id ='1') 
    UNION ALL SELECT `customer_entity_datetime`.* FROM `customer_entity_datetime` WHERE (entity_id ='1') 
    UNION ALL SELECT `customer_entity_text`.* FROM `customer_entity_text` WHERE (entity_id ='1')
```

replace `entity_id = 1` withe your customer id.
but there is a catch. You have to now to find a way to map the results from the first select, the one that retrieves the attributes with the one that retrieves the values.

Comment: can u give refrence of latest magento database diagram like this https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Finchoo.net%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2008%2F10%2Fmagento_v116-database_diagram.pdf&ei=fr9YVIuQO4utacbxgtgH&usg=AFQjCNFxPOgP0Znf9doum0bkhgRWBXrU6A&bvm=bv.78677474,d.d2s   but this is old i need new one....pls

Comment: @dkstackKumar. Sorry, I don't have one.

Comment: GOOD answer @Marius .upvote from me.. gave good idea

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get all the details of Customer entity, then you should use magento default functionality.

```
$customerData = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id)->getData();
```

And your query will not give all the details of customer, as Magento is using EAV model.
So all the details of Customer Entity is stored in different attributes tables.

If you want to have all details by manual query then you have to make joins of all other tables related to customer entity.

Best of Luck

Comment: I know...bt i need joined query ...for customer data...